# Can I determine the key of the query_result array in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

in `get_poll` function in following `Poll` model:

```
class Poll_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function get_poll($parameter) {
        $this->db->select('question.id, question.title, question.question, answer.answer')->from('answer')->join('question', 'answer.question_id = question_id')->where('question.id',$parameter);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

Because I'm using join to get result from 2 table and  table `question` and `answer` both have column `content`, so in the result_array, the structure like this:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => favourate character [content] => Green ) 1
```

The there's only `answer content`, I think the `question content` was overwrite, because both of them have the same column 'content'. the table structure shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE `answer` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `answer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rename the columns inside the `->select()` call like this:

```
$this->db
    ->select('
        question.id id, 
        question.title title, 
        question.content question, 
        answer.content answer')
    ->from('answer')
    ->join('question', 'answer.question_id = question_id')
    ->where('question.id', $parameter);
```

The result rows now should contain a `question` and a `answer` index.